# How can I call a powershell script and log the commands and results to a text file?

Tags: powershell

Suppose I have `myscript.ps1` which contains:

```
ls
```

And I use the following command to call as script and log the *results* to a file

```
powershell .\myscript.ps1 > log.txt
```

The problem is when I look at `log.txt`I see just the directory results.

I would like to see the actual command `ls` as well, so when I look at log.txt I know what command happened and then the results.

Comment: Isn't it same as copying the contents of `myscript.ps1` to `log.txt`?

Comment: Try `Start-Transcript` as the first command in your script before the ls, and use that to log.  I think that'll work.

Answer (score 0):

Start-Transcript it captures the commands executed and the output

```
Start-Transcript -Path "c:\test\test.txt"
ls
```

Comment: That doesn't work.  I don't see the commands in the output file

Comment: I can't recreate that issue. It works fine for me. What version of powershell is in your transcription log in its header the `PSVersion:` Field. If i do it mine looks like this:

`PS C:\WINDOWS> ls`

`Directory: C:\WINDOWS`